# Capture Android App Launch and App Minimize events

Tags: android

I have to do capture Applaunch and App minimize events for myapp for Appirater integration. I have to show Appirater dialog for every 3rd app launch/app minimize

I followed the article

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

But i have a problem, i have many activities,fragments in Application.say some Activities extends FragmentActivity, some of the them are fragments and some of them extends Activity

But, as per the article, i have to extend all the activities using Base Activity

It implies the architecture changes for my application.

If i write the code separate for each activities, the Appirater wonk work proper. Any alternatives to this ? please help in fixing

Tried also by extending Application class but it can capture app minimze events

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseActivity And a BaseFragmentActivity that does the same as the BaseActivity in the example, and then extend them in the appropriate places, should still work the same and you don't have to do much work. Correct me if I'm wrong, I just skimmed through it

Edit, example:

```
  public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
   //everything

  }
```

and the other

```
   public class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
   //everything
  }
```

Comment: Tried implementing as you suggested. but i got errors in my code like the sentences getSupportFragmentManager() saying The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined

Comment: you're probably going to have to override but not change those methods in your BaseFragmentActivity

Comment: it worked, but it fails my requirement. i have to add condition such that if the user clicks remind me button, we have to show the message in the next app launch. but, while navigating between the activities it is checking the method appicationwilenterforeground() in onstart() of Base Activity. it leading to call apprirater dialog in every activity.
   
String reminder_later_pressed = prefs.getString("isRemindMeLaterSelected", "");

if(((counter%3==0) || (reminder_later_pressed.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))))
   {  
     
   Appirater.appLaunched(BaseFragmentActivity.this);  
   
   }

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this but if you want to show this message on launch if some condition is true then just have it in your mainactivity?